# What is the best way to set up a daemon process in django

Tags: python, django, redis

I am working on an exchange related program that matches buy and sell orders from clients. I am new to django and I am trying to figure out the best way to implement my logic.

Suppose I have a coroutine that accepts a stream of client generated data like so:

```
@coroutine     #primes coroutine
def waiter(q):
    
    """
    Accepts orders from clients, sorts and puts them in a processing queue
    
    """
  
   sell_orders = []
   buy_orders = []
    while True:
        size, price, order = yield
        orderq = sell_orders if order == "sell" else buy_orders
        orderq.append((size, price, order))
        orderq.sort(key = lambda x: x[0], x[1]) #can this be done in redis?
        q.put(sellOrders[0], buyOrders[0])
```

And suppose I have a daemon process that checks the queue and processes the data like so:

```
def chef(q):
    """
    Daemon process, checks queue for orders
    Match orders when buy price is > than sell price
    """
    sleep = 5
    while True:
        if not q.empty():
            buy, sell = q.get()
            buy_price, sell_price = buy[0], sell[0]
            if buy_price >= sell_price:
                print("Make Trade")
        else:
            time.sleep(sleep)

q = Queue(maxsize=0)
t = Thread(target = chef, args =(q,) )
t.setDaemon(True)
t.start()
```

I can pass orders to the waiters like so:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = Waiter(q)
    buy = (300, 350, "buy", "usd")
    sell = (300, 349, "sell","usd")
    m.send(buy)
    m.send(sell)
```

In my Django project, the orders will be created by the users through userforms.  What I am really confused about is the best way to

**a) Collect and store the data**: I would like to replicate what the waiter function is doing in a more scalable way.  Is it best to use redis for this type of thing?  I am not familiar with redis, but from my research so far it seems I can't easily customize the sorting of a redis list like I would in python.

**b) Run the daemon process**: What it is best practice for running daemon processes like this in Django?

Comment: have you tried celery and channels perhaps?

Comment: Thanks Redgren, I have read up a bit on celery, but got a bit confused on how it could work in this case.  Suppose I have a celery task i.e the chef daemon in this case, can I then use Channels for my data collection and sorting logic? I apologize if I'm coming across as being too naive, I don't have much experience with either, so only just researching them